# Dialog box with textbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code for implementing a dialog box with textbox on it:

```
public static native void showEmailModal(String title)/*-{
    $wnd.$("<div><input id='emailAddresss' type='text'>Test</input></div>")
        .text("Enter email address:")
        .appendTo("body")
        .dialog({
            title: title,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            hide: "fade",
            show: "fade",
            buttons: {
                "Send": function() {
                    $wnd.$(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $wnd.$(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });    
}-*/;
```

The problem I have with this is that the input does not show up in the dialog box. What could I be missing here?

As part of the function I also need to send the value of the text input to a method for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the content (including the input field) with the `.text()` method.

Use this instead:

```
$("<div></div>")
        .html("Enter email address: <input id='emailAddresss' type='text'>")
```

Also, `<input>` can't have child nodes, i.e. `<input>Test</input>` is invalid.

Comment: How do I read the input div, crated with .html() method on the "Send" event?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "reading the input div" mean? Getting the value the user typed? You'd target it just like anything else (`$('#emailAddresss').val()` *[sic]*)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language/framework this is, but I'm going to assume the non-jQuery stuff is correct.

This line:

```
$("<div><input id='emailAddresss' type='text'>Test</input></div>")
```

Creates a new `div`, and this line:

```
.text("Enter email address:")
```

Sets the `div` element's text to `Enter email address:`, which overwrites/removes the input.

Also, `input` elements are self-closing: `<input type="text" value="Test" />`